# Open window on mouse co-ordinates

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I was wondering if it was possible to open a window where the mouse currently is? I have the current mouse co-ordinate but am unable to find what to do with the x y values when displaying my window.

Hopefully someone could point me in the direction of the appropriate method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, using the MouseInfo class will get the x and y position.

```
Point location = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
```

You specified that you want to use a JFrame in this case, so setting the location of the JFrame to this x and y point will do so.

```
Point location = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation(); 
int x = (int) location.getX();
int y = (int) location.getY();
JFrame frame = new JFrame(); //this is just the initialization of the window
frame.setLocation(x, y);
```

Comment: Just expanded on the JFrame part.

Comment: I tried this approach last night, it still defaults to the top left hand corner of my screen :/

Answer (score 0):

user1181445 was right, but I think you can set the frame location without creating the variables `x` and `y`:

```
Point location = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation(); 
JFrame frame = new JFrame(); //this is just the initialization of the window
frame.setLocation(location);
```